# take action when two specific values are selected in a Qlikview listbox

Tags: listbox, qlikview

Quick QlikView 11 question: I have a ListBox associated with Customers (a column from a database table). 
Of course, the Customers tables has many different values, but I am interested in showing "YES" in a textbox when values "Customer A" and "Customer B" are selected by the user from that ListBox.
What I tried so far:

```
=if(Customers="Customer A" AND Customers="Customer B", "YES", "NO")
```

This doesn't work.
(I obtain "NO" as a result instead of "YES", despire the fact the two mentioned values are selected from the ListBox)
Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found this to work:

```
if( SubStringCount ( GetFieldSelections(Customers),'Customer A,Customer B') >= 1 OR SubStringCount ( GetFieldSelections(Customers),'Customer B,Customer A') >= 1 , 'Yes', 'No')
```

If anyone has other ideas, feel free to mention them. This is just one possible solution.

Comment: If your customer list is not dynamic you can move the logic in the script - create new field with Yes/No values based on the customer name. Its easier to maintain and having such dynamic expressions in big app will decrease the performance of the app in overall.